# How to call a partial while inside a macro

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, macros, umbraco

I have a macro that is being used to loop through a media type full of carousel images. **That** part, as well as the if statement defining which image I really want, is working beautifully as a banner. My problem is that the banner is supposed to have breadcrumbs over top that allow the user to go back a page in the directory. The code is a little complicated, so it's in a partial in an attempt to make things cleaner. The partial won't render. Right now, I have it commented out so that I can work with the macro, but as soon as I uncomment it the macro breaks. This is how I'm trying to render the partial: @Html.Partial("_BreadCrumbs")

I've tried researching this, but no matter what keywords I use my searches bring up how to render a macro inside a partial... which is the complete opposite of what I want. Also, the code I'm using to render the partial is the same code I would be using in a Template, which works.

[This](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/75771-how-can-i-render-a-partial-inside-a-macro) article helped me understand the problem more, but the solutions posed here haven't solved anything for me... The error that I keep getting is: Error loading Partial View script (file: ~/Views/MacroPartials/_BannerPicker.cshtml)

The directories actually look like below... I just omitted the one layer because I didn't think it was important.

Views > MacroPartials > SiteName > _BannerPicker.cshtml (the macro I'm working with)

Views > Partials > SiteName > _BreadCrumbs.cshtml (the partial I'm trying to display inside it)

Views > Template1

Views > Template 2

My code looks like this:

@Html.Partial("~/views/partials/sitename/_BreadCrumbs.cshtml")
If I comment out the above line of code the macro works just fine, so I know it's an issue connecting the two.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@{   
    Html.RenderPartial("~/views/partials/sitename/_BreadCrumbs.cshtml");
}
```